# read the content of send-q TCP socket in linux

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP client sending data to a server continuously . After successful connection of client with the server , client sends data continuously with some intervals in terms of few seconds .

When the link between the client and server got disconnected after sending few data ,I came to know that TCP retransmits the data according to the value in TCP_retries2 , I configured this value to be 8 , such that I get write error after 100 secs . 
But there will be some unacknowledged packets in send-q .

Is there way to read the content of this unacknowledged packets in send-q in my program before closing this socket or should i remember the send data and resend it after connecting again ? Is there any other way to implement this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the size of sendq with an ioctl:

```
SIOCOUTQ
          Returns the amount of unsent data in the socket send queue.
          The socket must not be in LISTEN state, otherwise an error
          (EINVAL) is returned.  SIOCOUTQ is defined in
          <linux/sockios.h>.  Alternatively, you can use the synonymous
          TIOCOUTQ, defined in <sys/ioctl.h>.
```

Note that sendq only tells you what the kernel of the remote system accepted, it does not guarantee that the application running on that host handled it. Most failures exist in the network between the communicating parties, but this metric can't be used for definite proof as successful transmission.

Comment: Assume 200 bytes was queued to send, and `SIOCOUTQ` returns 100, can I be sure it was the first 100 bytes that were acknowledged, or could have been the last 100, and the first was lost in routing?

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol, so bytes can only be ACKed if everything up to that byte is received, so yes, you can be sure it was the first 100 byte. (There's a TCP extension called SACK that sort of acknowledges the receipt of arbitrary chunks of data, but that doesn't alter the snd_una value of the tcp struct, so what I wrote should still be correct even if SACK is being used.)

Answer (score 1):

Once the application has given its data to TCP, it is the responsibility of TCP to keep track of the acknowledgement of the packets. If ACKs are not forthcoming, it tries its best to get the packet delivered based on RTO  algorithm. Now until ACK is received, the data is kept in TCP_SEND_Q. I do not think there is any control from the application to determine *current* state of TCP_SEND_Q.

//should i remember the send data and resend it after connecting again//

How do you do this? The previous connection status is gone, isn't? Until the client and the server applications maintain some understanding as to what was received and sent offline, you have to start fresh with new connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently I don't have any application level acknowledgement . I thought of sending all the data which i sent 100 secs before i get the retransmit time_out error from client side . I have to think about the application level acknowledgements .

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't.

If you need to know that the peer application has received the data, you need to have the peer application acknowledge it back to your application via your application protocol, and treat any unacknowledged data as needing re-sending from your application somehow. This also brings in the question of transactional idempotence, so that you can resend with impunity.

Answer (score -1):

It takes two to tango.  You can close your end of the connection and it waits for the other end of the connection to drop, too.  Think 3-way handshake in reverse.

How long do you wait between closing the connectiion and re-opening it?  You must wait at least the TIME_WAIT before trying to reconnect using the same connection info.

Comment: TCP waits for the other end to drop the connection, but your application doesn't wait. The close() function is asynchronous. You only need to wait for TIME_WAIT if you reuse the same local port at the client, and there is no reason to do that other Han bozo firewall rules on outbound port numbers, which should be removed, as they accomplish precisely nothing and render applications unimplementable. And you haven't actually answered the question.